# Mostly SPArtistBrowse's firstPortrait is nil

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm doing a search to the Spotify service and receiving all artists for that search. Then I'm making SPArtistBrowse objects from the artists-objects I'm receiving and want to use the firstPortrait property as cover images for the artists, the problem is that the most firstPortraits are nil. When I'm searching for artists on the Spotify app for iOS they appear with pictures. Is the Spotify app showing the cover for an album on the artist if the firstPortrait is nil or am I doing something wrong?

Example: An artist where the firstPortrait is nil on my app and where the Spotify app is showing a picture is the artist HOFFMAESTRO.

Here's a snippet from my implementation:

```
SPArtist *artist = (SPArtist*)[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
SPArtistBrowse *artistBrowse = [SPArtistBrowse browseArtist:artist inSession:[SPSession sharedSession] type:SP_ARTISTBROWSE_FULL];            

[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:artistBrowse
                        timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout
                           then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems){

     // mostly artistBrowse.firstPortrait is nil                                   
    [self fadeCoverImage:artistBrowse.firstPortrait forCell:cell];
}];
```

EDIT: Should say that the artistBrowse object is loaded when fadeCoverImage:forCell: is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many artists in Spotify don't have portraits. In this case, the official clients substitute in an album cover instead — indeed, HOFFMAESTRO uses an album cover as the picture.

Using an album cover image when an artist doesn't have a portrait image is the standard thing to do here.